# How to separate sub-menu output and keep associated with parent

Tags: menus, wp-admin, sub-menu

I am creating a menu like this https://squareup.com/ I have the html,css, and jquery ready. Now, I am trying to:

Create the menu items with it's sub-menu items via `wp-admin -> appearance -> menus` **( which I have done )**

output the menu item with it's corresponding sub-menu items separately and dynamically.

```
 <header>
        <?php if ( get_field('landing_hero_image') ): ?>
                <div class="menu" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('landing_hero_image'); ?>);">
                    <a class="click-me">
                        main menu item
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-content">
                    sub menu item associated with the main item
                </div>
                <div class="banner" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('landing_hero_image'); ?>);">
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
```

So to summarize, how do I separate the output ( html ) menu items and their children?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Register the navigation menu location in your theme's `functions.php` file using [the `register_nav_menu()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu), assign your custom menu to the location in *Dashboard > Appearance > Menus*, then use [the `wp_nav_menu()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) in your theme's template files to print the menu's markup where appropriate.

Refer to the [overview of Navigation Menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) in the Codex.

Comment: I know how to do that, that does not answer my question. I did not ask how to register menus.

Comment: Yes it does. You are attempting to recreate functionality built-in to WordPress, which is counter-intuitive and unnecessary. The steps I've provided detail exactly how to produce the markup for your custom menu. If the result doesn't fit your needs, edit your question to indicate the problem. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help].

Comment: No it doesn't. I am simply asking how to divide a menu item with its sub menu items in html mark-up, but retain the parent child relationship and have the partent trigger the associative child container. I have created the menu, so in this case I don't need to register a new menu. Not sure how that is 'counter-intuitive and unnecessary.

Comment: Then don't register a new menu - you've clearly accomplished the registration step, move on to using `wp_nav_menu()` to print it out. You can achieve the same affect seen on the linked website without separating the parent/sub-menu markup. It is drastically easier to achieve the affect with CSS than to change the way WordPress prints menu HTML just to match that site's markup.

Comment: If you insist on separating items, look into the `wp_get_navigation_menu_items()` function, or maybe read up on creating your own `Walker_Nav_Menu` class.

Comment: Thanks that helps. How do I achieve that effect on the site while retaining my html markup? You're saying I can do that with CSS? Please edit answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: My apologies for not grasping the problem completely. I had not realized the sub-menus on the referenced site dynamically altered the rest of the page layout. It's possible to do with CSS *and* JavaScript (in order to adjust the layout to account for `absolute`ly-positioned submenus), but splitting the items into separate parent/children containers as you originally wanted to makes a lot of sense. I'll post a solution to what you were originally after later tonight.

Comment: No problem. The help is appreciated. @ bosco